# Keyboard push the whole content to black background (cordova+framework7+vue)

Tags: ios, cordova, vue.js, webview, html-framework-7

I have input in toolbar bottom. When keyboard comes up, the content somehow is pushed to (too) top and appear to have black background.
I have

```
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.shrinkView(true)
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true)
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(true)
```

Here is the spec:

```
cordova 8.0.0
cordova-plugin-keyboard 1.2.0 "Keyboard"
<engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.5" />
```

Example of bug https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc2Fe.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This might a be problem of organising page contents that does not fit vertically into viewport. As an work around try scroll it to original position by the time keyboard appears. (Example code is below)

```
 $("#SearchInput").focus(function(){
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    });
```

Comment: And there is an issue in Xcode 10 that view is not returning back to original position when Keyboard is closed. Hope that helps someone.